# RactiveJS decorator init issue

Tags: ractivejs

I am using a decorator for some sliders like the following:

```
content = new Ractive({
    el: '.wrapper',
    template: templates.wrapper,
    partials: templates,
    data : { ... },
    decorators: {
        carousel: function( node )
        {
            console.log( 'carousel init' );
            carousel = $( node ).owlCarousel({ 
                items: 1,
                navigation: false 
            });

            return {
                teardown: function () {
                    console.log( 'carousel destroy' );
                    carousel.trigger('destroy.owl.carousel').removeClass('owl-carousel owl-loaded');
                    carousel.find('.owl-stage-outer').children().unwrap();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What happens is that, as you can see in the logs, when swapping between a template which has `inited` the carousel to another template that has this decorator as well, the first decorator `teardown` is being triggered after the new template's decorator is `initiated`, therefore the carousel on the second template gets `torn down` and not the one in the first template.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong ? Thanks !

### *UPDATE*

I have made a jsfiddle for it here : https://jsfiddle.net/05sq8o2k/6/

Make sure to tap `load unsafe scripts` if you get the warning because `ractivejs` cdn does not support `https` as far as I can see so jsfiddle kind of disagrees with it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems fixed in the next version of Ractive. Update your fiddle to use: https://cdn.ractivejs.org/edge/ractive.min.js

Kind regards

Bob